# FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Enter the same currency as the parent Order.: Currency ISO Code: [CurrencyIsoCode]

Tags: salesforce, apex

We have enabled multi currency in our org. After enabling multicurrency the Quotes that we convert with EUR currency Code are creating Orders without line items, with the error message as below.

FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Enter the same currency as the parent Order.: Currency ISO Code: [CurrencyIsoCode]

We had a class that used to process Quotes to Orders. When I checked that class, I can see that both Currency and PriceBooks are hardcoded. The class is as below.

```
public with sharing class PRXS_Quote_Service {
    private static final String CURRENCY_CODE                       = 'USD';
        private static final String QUOTE_SUCCESSFULL_TITLE             = 'Quote Import Completed Succesfully';
        private static final String QUOTE_SUCCESSFULL_BODY              = 'Your quote has finished processing and has been imported successfully';
        public static final  String ERROR_TYPE_DATA_ERROR               = 'Data Error';
        public static final  String ERROR_TYPE_SYSTEM_EXCEPTION         = 'System Exception';
        public static final  String PRICEBOOK                           = 'Standard Price Book';
    
        //private static API_QuoteLoadRuleRunner productRulesRunner = new API_QuoteLoadRuleRunner();
        private static API_QuoteSaver quoteSaver = new API_QuoteSaver();
        private static API_QuoteReader quoteReader = new API_QuoteReader();
        private static API_QuoteProductAdder quoteProductAdder = new API_QuoteProductAdder();
        private static API_QuoteProductReader productReader = new API_QuoteProductReader();
        private static Map<String, ProductModel> configsByProduct2Code = new Map<String, ProductModel>();
        private static String  priceBookId = '';
        private static List<Default_Filter_Field_To_Add__mdt> defaultFiltersToUse = new List<Default_Filter_Field_To_Add__mdt>();
       
        private static void loadDefaultFilterValues() {
        
            if (defaultFiltersToUse.isEmpty()) {
                defaultFiltersToUse = [SELECT Id, Default_Value__c, Product_Option_Field_Name__c FROM Default_Filter_Field_To_Add__mdt];
            }
        }
    
        private static String getPriceBook() {
            
            if (String.isBlank(priceBookId)) {
                List<Pricebook2> books = [SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE Name = : PRICEBOOK LIMIT 1];
                for(Pricebook2 pb : books) {
                    priceBookId = pb.Id;
                }
            }
    
            return priceBookId;
        } 

}
```

How can I change this? How can fetch the right values for currency and price book and assign them them in the places where the values are hardcoded?

Can we query Quote by getting the Quote ID in this class and fetch CurrencyISOCode and priceBookId through Quote record? If yes, how can I accomplish that.

Thanks in advance.